# Deleting items (gitObjectType: blob) from AzureDevOps using REST API

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a script (in Python) that will delete given Items from Azure DevOps repository using REST API. And I'm losing my hope it is possible.

Let's say I have a list of objects, listed with a sample request from the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items?scopePath=/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views&recursionLevel=Full&includeContentMetadata=true&api-version=6.0
```

And the part of the example result:

```
(...)
{
      "objectId": "9093f030aa7dd8c802cad228fae4c6bafae4b32f",
      "gitObjectType": "blob",
      "commitId": "23d0bc5b128a10056dc68afece360d8a0fabb014",
      "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/Index.cshtml",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/Index.cshtml?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
    },
    {
      "objectId": "61a86fdaa79e5c6f5fb6e4026508489feb6ed92c",
      "gitObjectType": "blob",
      "commitId": "23d0bc5b128a10056dc68afece360d8a0fabb014",
      "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
    },
    {
      "objectId": "445986f7957f0478686b6def4dcd04d2bad00594",
      "gitObjectType": "blob",
      "commitId": "23d0bc5b128a10056dc68afece360d8a0fabb014",
      "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Login.cshtml",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Login.cshtml?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
    }
(...)
```

Is there any way to delete one of the blobs using REST API?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: One of the things a Git hash represents is the state of the system, including all the blobs. If you could just delete one of them, then the hash would be invalid, and your repo would be corrupted.

Comment: The correct way to "delete" something is to make a new commit that deletes it. If you need it to appear as if it never existed, then you should re-write the entire history starting from before it was added to the repo.

Comment: Note that *Git* does not have a REST API. Various hosting sites have REST APIs but how to use those APIs is per-hosting-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you for your support.

I resolved the problem. The steps were taken:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1  -> for getting the objectId of the given branch. This objectId was neccessary for the next step (as "oldObjectId")
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#delete-a-file